# how can create a prediction interval based on a linear model in SAS

Tags: sas, regression, linear-regression

I am trying to create a prediction interval in SAS. My SAS code is

```
Data M;
input y x;
datalines;
100 20
120 40
125 32
..
;
proc reg;
model y = x / clb clm alpha =0.05;
Output out=want p=Ypredicted;
run;
data want;
set want;
y1= Ypredicted;
proc reg data= want;
   model y1 = x / clm cli;
run;
```

but when I run the code I could find the new Y1 how can I predict the new Y?

Comment: The term you're looking for is 'Score'. Google "how to score a model SAS".

Comment: https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2014/02/19/scoring-a-regression-model-in-sas.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do is score your model, which takes the results from the regression and uses them to estimate new values.

The most common way to do this in SAS is simply to use [`PROC SCORE`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/68162/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_score_toc.htm).  This allows you to take the output of `PROC REG` and apply it to your data.

To use `PROC SCORE`, you need the `OUTEST=` option (think 'output estimates') on your `PROC REG` statement.  The dataset that you assign there will be the input to `PROC SCORE`, along with the new data you want to score.

As Reeza notes in comments, this is covered, along with a bunch of other ways to do this that might work better for you, in Rick Wicklin's blog post, [Scoring a regression model in SAS](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2014/02/19/scoring-a-regression-model-in-sas.html).